# ClassNotFoundException on accessing the entity that is declared outside the dynamic web project

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La55w.png)When the Hibernate Entity bean(Product.java in testService) is declared outside the dymanic web project, hibernate could not load the class Product.java. But when Product.java is placed in testWeb it is working fine. 
Please help to access the Entity that is declared outside the dynamic web project.

Project created in Eclipse Mars2

Project Structure:

testService 
--com.test.service.dao.entity 
----Product.java

testWeb
--src
----config.db
------hibernate-cfg.xml
----config.db.mapping
------userdetails.hbm.xml
--WebContent
----WEB-INF
------lib
--------all jar files

EAR Deployment Assemble: 
testService - lib/testService.jar
testWeb- testWeb.war

Error:

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [file:/D:/workspace/project/test/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/testWeb/WEB-INF/classes/config/db/hibernate-cfg.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not found: com.test.service.dao.entity.Product
May 08, 2016 11:26:53 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [file:/D:/workspace/project/test/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/testWeb/WEB-INF/classes/config/db/hibernate-cfg.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not found: com.test.service.dao.entity.Product
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not found: com.test.service.dao.entity.Product
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getMappedClass(PersistentClass.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.getGetter(PropertyFactory.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierAttribute(PropertyFactory.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:509)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.test.service.dao.entity.Product]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.ClassLoaderAccessImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderAccessImpl.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getMappedClass(PersistentClass.java:127)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : com.test.service.dao.entity.Product
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:217)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
    ... 44 more
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add a screen for the project structure. It is not clear to me.

Comment: Hi, I don't have privilege to attach the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added testService project to testWeb "Deployment Assembly" and now it works.

Thanks.